# astype(int) doesn't stay in place

Tags: python, pandas

My question is: does anyone recognise this Pandas Jupiter problem. I do what I always do but suddenly things are not going the way they should go....

1. why, why changes the type back to the original type and
2. why is the type after writing to csv from notebook and reloading back, changed back to the original type.....

I must be overheated or something, can't figure it out. Somehow Jupyter has a bug or I have forgotten some basic coding.... I tried this in base environment as well in a new virt Conda env. Thanks for the help / suggestions!!!

I have a csv, I import this with:

```
df=pd.read_csv('df_test.csv')
```

`df.info()` (only the lines needed for my question)

[image]

I make a copy of my df:

```
df2=df.copy()
```

df2.info is the same:

[image]

I want to make Opnameduur, OK TIJD and Snijtijd integers. I do this one by one:

```
df2.astype({'Opnameduur': 'int32'}).dtypes
```

This works:

Then I change OK TIJD:

```
df2.astype({'OK TIJD': 'int32'}).dtypes
```

THis works BUT.... Opnameduur changed back to float....

This is the same as I change types in one batch.

Also: when writing the df2 to CSV (with for example Opnameduur changed to int32), reloading the csv in my notebook shows with .info(), that all three are yet back again on float.

df2.info():
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, astype is no inplace function. You have to assign this to keep your changes ```df2 = df2.astype({'OK TIJD': 'int32'})```

Comment: ...and while you are already using a dict for the change, shouldn't this result in your intended result in a simpler way? ```df2 = df2.astype({'OK TIJD': 'int32', 'Opnameduur': 'int32'})```

Comment: Racooneer thanks, but this gives a series back and not a dataframe onfortunally...

Comment: in retrospective, yes, makes sense. ```df2["OK TIJD"] = df2.astype({'OK TIJD': 'int32'})``` or rather ```df2[["OK TIJD", "Opnameduur"]] = df2.astype({'OK TIJD': 'int32', , 'Opnameduur': 'int32'})```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and it works! Many thanks Racooner!!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)